# Windows10 Windows Explorer File Search Troubles

Tags: search, windows-10, git-bash, atom-editor, windows-explorer

I'm working on a very large library, and I just want to look at all the files that end simply in `.h`    Unfortunately when I go to Windows Explorer, select my directory of interest, go to the top right hand box and type in `*.h`   the fricking thing reacts like I typed in `*.h*` so I get a whole ton of files that I'm not interested in (those that end in .hpp, .hlsl, etc...)

I can't figure out how to get exactly what I'm looking for.  I've tried many variations, nothing seems to work. Is this representative of a mediocre design decision on the part of the Microsoft folks?  Aaaargh!

Is there a way to get Windows Explorer to function like I want it to? Is there a better way to navigate a large multi-tiered directory to search precisely for `*.h` files, from within the Win10 OS using common developer tools?  (Command line, Visual Studio, Git bash Command line, atom.io plugin, etc?)

Comment: `type:header` (matches the Type column) Personally I use multicommander which as a simple wildcard filter that sticks between folder selections

Comment: I've tried that, its a fail for me, in fact I got worse results that way.  I think the `*."h"` thing works best.  Note: `Type:c/c++ Header` does work.

Answer (score 3):

Ouch.  You have to use `*."h"`   Not what I would call very intuitive.   Per the note from AlexK, `Type:c/c++ Header` also does work to perform the search accurately.

One more trick I learned while I was here.  There is an option to sort the search results in windows explorer (choose the top View tab, then Sort by button...)  Pretty handy way to organize your analysis of a complex library.

Comment: `"*.h"` works too. Or using Powershell `dir -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {$_.Name like "*.h"}`